# Dead kitchen outlets

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have 6 dead daisy chained outlets in the kitchen.  Continuity test were good on the receptacles so it’s a wiring issue (no wire nuts seen in #1 to #5 electrical boxes). Resetting 6 GFCIs did not help.  I used a Cent tech cable tracker to confirm that all 6 outlets are on the same circuit. However, I could not trace power going to #1 outlet using same cable tracker. I heard a combination of faint tone and buzzing all over the place (I turned off breakers to all lights and outlets in the house). # 6 outlet only has line coming in (no line out)
However, I found an extra (capped)black wire that has power inside #6 electrical box. I switched out the dead black wire for this and the outlet worked. Looking inside the electrical box, there are 3 sets of wires coming in. The left one has black,red, white and ground. The middle has black, white and ground, and same goes for the one on the right.
The red wire is connected to the black wire from the right bundle.  The dead black wire comes from the middle bundle. The capped/hot black wire comes from the left bundle.
I plugged in a blender/juicer in this outlet and it didn’t trip the breaker. Left it hooked up overnight with no issues.

I’m curious if there are any safety issues I should be concerned with? Also can I hook up the dead outlets to #6 by reversing the lines in(meaning hooking up the original line out as line in. Do I need 2 white/neutrals on #6 or just leave the pigtail that was already connected? Please see attached pics and kitchen layout. Sorry for the long post and newbie questions. If I’m way over my head on this one, I’ll gladly heed your advice to call an electrician. Thanks in advance.
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box for #1 outlet please?

Comment: Hi, please see added pics.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Does the hot black wire in #6 also come with a white wire?  We really need to know how the **wires** are grouped into **cables**.

Comment: Yes, the black wire in #6 comes with a white wire (see first pic). A wire nut secures all 3 white wires. From there, a white pigtail connects to the outlet.         Also, here’s a part of my initial post above.” Looking inside the electrical box, there are 3 sets of wires coming in. The left one has black,red, white and ground. The middle has black, white and ground, and same goes for the one on the right. The red wire is connected to the black wire from the right bundle. The dead black wire comes from the middle bundle. The capped/hot black wire comes from the left bundle.”.  Thanks!

Comment: The white wires and the ground wire on that outlet are wrapped around their screws the wrong way (according to my own personal electric code). Whenever possible I suggest wrapping the wires clockwise around the screw. This is so that when the screw is tightened the wire is pulled in under the screw head rather than being pushed out away from it (for example, the wire under the top screw is barely attached).

Comment: Greg the code has descriptions of the proper way in article 110 the descriptions are for aluminum wire but the same holds true for copper 2/3-3/4  clockwise wrap so the tail is pulled in when tightening not pushed out.